# Removing a form field (select) when form submits

Tags: php, html, forms, appointment

Is there a way for when someone selects a  field option and submits the form, that the form will then not sure that  field anymore?

Basically I'm trying to make an appointment list in with the  field and when someone makes an appointment with that specific time, I want that time to disappear so no one else can select it.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You will need to save all the already selected options somehow. Have you thought about how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself to solve this? Generally on SO, you are supposed to try something, then ask questions if it isn't working - not to mention it makes it a LOT easier for folks to help pin-point an error rather than writing code from start to finish.

Answer (score 0):

You would need the date and time information stored in the database.

Basically then when loading the form you'd populate only those dates and times that are unused and then when the user submits the form, update the database with the newly selected date/time.